# Angular HTML doesn't load properly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, devextreme

I will try to describe my problem as simple as it is. I have front on Angular (12.2.16) and back in c#. It was working before full upgrade of dependencies and then accidentally it stopped work. Previous version of angular was 9.0.0. This issue is extremely strange because sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.

Here is an example what's going on:
[login form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pqbk.png) before logging

After logout and route to /main this one looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASWUl.png)

It isn't the only one thing. When I am on the user dashboard there is few pages which are behaving same way as the form. Please could you at least try to give me possible solutions - how can I debug it properly and find the error which is causing these issues.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod": "ng build --prod",
    "build-staging": "ng build --configuration staging",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build-themes": "devextreme build",
    "postinstall": "npm run build-themes"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.15",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.15",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.15",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.15",
    "@angular/material": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.15",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.15",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^3.0.0",
    "@material-extended/mde": "^3.0.3",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^8.1.1",
    "devextreme": "21.2.5",
    "devextreme-angular": "21.2.5",
    "devextreme-aspnet-data-nojquery": "^2.8.6",
    "devextreme-schematics": "^1.2.24",
    "ngx-drag-scroll": "^12.0.0-beta.2",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^13.0.0",
    "ngx-lightbox": "^2.5.2",
    "ngx-material-file-input": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.15",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.15",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.2.15",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "devextreme-cli": "latest",
    "devextreme-themebuilder": "21.2.5",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.11",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.
Please don't put links to screenshots.

Comment: From the images it seems that your text is missing from the components - are you getting the text through some subscription or have it set in components themselves?